# Undefined method 'link_to_add_nested' in Rails 7 using vanilla-nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using this: https://github.com/arielj/vanilla-nested in Rails 7 to dynamically add nested fields on a form.  I am following a Udemy course that is a bit out of date, which uses Rails 5, so I'm not getting any help from there.  The course is using the Cocoon gem, but that appears to not have been updated in several years and I initially thought my error was stemming from that, so, after some searching, I switched to the vanilla-nested one.  With both packages, I get the same error in the same place, so I think it must be something in my code that is the cause.  I have searched extensively and have not found anything helpful.

In case this helps anything, I am using esbuild not importmap.  cocoon and vanilla-nested were added using yarn.  I have included the application.js file below in case it is something with that configuration.  jquery is working for bootstrap and if I do $ === jquery in the console, I get true as the response.  vanilla-nested doesn't use jquery, so I don't think the problem is related to that. I removed the import tag for cocoon when I switched over to vanilla-nested. Please let me know if there is anything else I can add.

Here is the error:

> undefined method `link_to_add_nested' for
> #ActionView::Base:0x00000000011350
>
> ```
>   '.freeze;@output_buffer.append=( link_to_add_nested(f, :technologies, 'Add Technology') );@output_buffer.safe_append='
>                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Did you mean?  link_to_next_page
> ```

**app/views/portfolios/_form.html.erb file**

```rb
<%= form_for(@portfolio_item) do |f| %>

#snip irrelevant code

  <h2>Technologies Used</h2>
    <div>
      <%= f.fields_for :technologies do |technology_form| %>
      <%= render 'technology_fields', f: technology_form %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= link_to_add_nested(f, :technologies, 'Add Technology') %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Save Portfolio Item", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block'%>
    </div>
    <% end %>   </div>
```

**app/models/portfolio.rb**

```rb
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord   has_many :technologies, dependent: :destroy   
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :technologies,
                                 reject_if: lambda { |attrs| attrs['name'].blank? }
    
   validates_presence_of :title, :body
    
   mount_uploader :thumb_image, PortfolioUploader   mount_uploader :main_image, 
   PortfolioUploader
    
   def self.angular
     where(subtitle: 'Angular')   
   end
    
   def self.by_position
     order("position ASC")   
   end
    
   scope :ruby_on_rails_portfolio_items, -> { where(subtitle: 'Ruby on Rails') } 
end
```

**app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb**

```rb
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_portfolio_item, only: %i[ show edit update destroy move ]
  access all: [:show, :index, :angular], user: { except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit, :move] }, admin: :all
  layout "portfolio"

  def index
    @portfolio_items = Portfolio.by_position
  end

  def angular
    @angular_portfolio_items = Portfolio.angular
  end

  def new
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new
  end

  def create
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Your portfolio item is now live' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.update(portfolio_params)
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Portfolio item was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
    # Destroy the record
    @portfolio_item.destroy

    # Redirect
    #redirect_to portfolios_path, status: :see_other
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to portfolios_url, notice: 'Record was removed.' }
    end
  end

  def move
    @portfolio_item.insert_at(params[:position].to_i)
  end

  private

  def set_portfolio_item
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  end

  def portfolio_params
    params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title,
                                      :subtitle,
                                      :body,
                                      :main_image,
                                      :thumb_image,
                                      technologies_attributes: [:name])
  end
end
```

**app/javascript/application.js**

```js
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import './add_jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';
import '@hotwired/turbo-rails';
import './controllers';
import consumer from './channels/consumer';
import CableReady from 'cable_ready';
import mrujs from 'mrujs';
import { CableCar } from 'mrujs/plugins';

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
import 'vanilla-nested';
import './custom/portfolios';

mrujs.start({
    plugins: [new CableCar(CableReady)],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that you added this line to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'vanilla_nested'
```

and ran

```
bundle install
```

after updating the `Gemfile`. Additionally, after installing the gem you need to restart your application.

Comment: Thank you. I installed it via yarn.  It shows that it's there in the yarn.lock file.  I have also verified the presence of the folder with the other node modules. I have been restarting the application after every change.

Comment: I'm a dummy.  I just saw in the docs that you can install with yarn, but the gemfile is needed to for the helper methods.  That's what I get for reading too fast.  Thank you.